# Execute LightSwitch Javascript Asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, setinterval, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a `Back Button` within my Lightswitch Application which I need to link directly to a specific screen.
The linked screen requires a `ProjectID` value which I supply from the page which you are clicking `Back` on.

> The problem is that when I click back, I am brought to the right page but no records display until after a page refresh.  I need to refresh the page AFTER the load is complete

I have been messing with `setTimeout` and `setInterval` with no luck. Can this be done within my button click, or should I be using a different navigation method entirely?

Code with the `setTimeout` (doesn't navigate backward):

```
myapp.ViewRecordDetails.BackButton_execute = function (screen) {
    // window.history.back();
    showDetails = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.reload(true);
        }, 0)
    }
    window.location.reload(true);
};
```

Code which navigates back but needs the refresh to show data:

```
myapp.ViewRecordDetails.BackButton_execute = function (screen) {
    // window.history.back();
    myapp.showViewProjectDetails(screen.TBG_V_TimeLog_Detail), function () {
    }//Need to execute reload AFTER show screen has completed
};
```

You may notice that I have commented out `widow.history.back();`... this was working in the first iteration of my application, but there are now two different ways to land on the page so History is unreliable

Comment: A few questions:
- I'm assuming that you do something on the ViewRecordDetails screen that affects something you'd see on the ViewProjectDetails?
- What is the type of screen.TBG_V_TimeLog_Detail? Unless it's a ProjectDetail item, you won't get anything on the screen.
- After you're changing the data on the ViewRecordDetails screen (prior to hitting the BackButton), are you calling myapp.commitChanges() or myapp.applyChanges() ?

Comment: I have an SSRS report which directly links to `ViewRecordDetails` based on the `PrimaryKey`. You can also navigate to `ViewRecordDetails` from the home page of my application. These two approaches are why `history.back` wont work. `TBG_V_TimeLog_Detail` is my dataset and worked in another `showScreen` action which I have (code to follow). `ViewRecordDetails` could have no changes made and the `back` button will still show nothing before refresh...

Code for another `showScreen` button which works:

Comment: `myapp.ViewRecordDetails.EditComment_execute = function (screen) {
    myapp.showEditRecordDetails(screen.TBG_V_TimeLog_Detail, {
        afterClosed: function (editScreen) {
            myapp.ViewRecordDetails(screen.TBG_V_TimeLog_Detail);
        }
    });
};`

Comment: Curious, could you post a screenshot so I can see what you mean by "show nothing", then a screenshot of what it looks like when you refresh? I've just done a simple test on my side with a back button like yours and I always see data, though it may not be up to date when I navigate back. Doing the following ensured the data was up to date once I'd navigated back: `myapp.ViewFindingUpdate.Back_execute = function (screen) {
    myapp.showViewFinding(screen.FindingUpdate.Finding, {
        beforeShown: function (newScreen) {
            screen.FindingUpdate.details.refresh();
        }
    });
};`

Comment: For PII reasons I'd rather avoid screenshots :/

But my table says `No Items`. I tried your code, and substituted `screen.FindingUpdate.Finding` with my own `screen.TBG_V_TimeLog_Detail.ProjectID` which is the UniqueID which I want to pass to my screen upon going back. This code had me not going back at all, and removing the `.ProjectID` from that line resulted in the same `No Items` issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how I didn't get this before..

BobbyJ's response got me thinking about `commitChanges` which got me thinking about skipping javascript tricks, and using what I already had.

This code works:

```
myapp.ViewRecordDetails.BackButton_execute = function (screen) {
    // window.history.back();
    myapp.showViewProjectDetails(screen.TBG_V_TimeLog_Detail).then(function(){
         myapp.commitChanges()
            }).then(function () {
                window.location.reload(true);//Need to execute reload AFTER show screen has completed
    })
};
```

This is all that I actually needed though:

```
myapp.ViewRecordDetails.BackButton_execute = function (screen) {
    myapp.showViewProjectDetails(screen.TBG_V_TimeLog_Detail).then(function(){
                window.location.reload(true);
    })
};
```

Just utilizing the `.then()` functionality. Pretty nifty